# How do I install the original gnome-control-center?

Tags: gnome

How can I install in the Gnome-Shell in Ubuntu 12.10 the original gnome-control-center (ppa, package). In Ubuntu have it on version of the gnome-control-center. I mean the control-center from Fedora, Gnome-Live CD...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to convert the *.rpm (from Fedora) to a *.deb (which Ubuntu can handle) with Alien.

Herefor you

1. download the rpm from the [Fedora Package Database](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/builds/show/F-14-i386/control-center/1/2.32.0/1.fc14/i686)
2. install Alien with **sudo apt-get install alien**
3. convert and install the file with **alien -i filename.rpm**

Source: http://www.howtoforge.com/converting_rpm_to_deb_with_alien